# Meteor: how to extract id of first item from a collection

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor collection and want to get the id of the first item. The query has a limit 1 clause and I just want the id of the first item if there is one. I can't figure out how to code it.

Here is my query.

```
  var myGames = Games.find(
     {
       game_minutes: {$gt: MinutesSinceMidnightNow},
       court_id: court,
       game_date: {$gt: lastMidnight}
       },
       {
         sort: { "game_minutes": 1},
         limit: 1
       });
```

Then, if I iterate over the results, my app goes off to the races.

```
   myGames.forEach(function (game) {

     gameId = game._id;

     console.log('gameId: ' + gameId );

  });
```

I know the query is working and currently returning a record but I can't figure out how to access the record.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

find() returns a cursor. Instead of using `forEach` use `fetch` which will fetch all data from the cursor to an array. So in your case:

```
var id = myGames.fetch()[0]._id;
```

(when you are certain that the data is there. otherwise check if array is not empty)

Comment: And if you only want to fetch one document, one should use `findOne(selector)` instead of `find(selector).fetch()[0]`.

Comment: yup, this is the equivalent

Comment: In my application I have this is the same function as a call to remove and reload games. This line causes a race condition.